# How to track deleted rows from database system versioned table in Azure SQL/SQL Server?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have system versioned Customer table and need to track if admin user deleted the row ('Tesla') from the table.

CustomerHistory table do get new row for 'Tesla', but it does not explicitly tell if row has been updated or deleted.

I would need advice to create SELECT/INSERT SQL query, which compared Customers and CustomerHistory to check which row has been deleted and insert the row ('Tesla') to CustomersDeleted table.

I have System versioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE [sales].[Customers](
    [Customer_PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Customer_Id] [smallint] NULL,
    [Customer_Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It has value '1','100','Tesla' and '2','200','Ford'.
Admin user will deleted 'Tesla' row.

I have History versioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE [sales].[CustomersHistory](
    [Customer_PK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer_Id] [smallint] NULL,
    [Customer_Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have third table where I would like to insert rows ('Tesla') that has been removed from Customer table.

```
CREATE TABLE [sales].[CustomersDeleted](
    [Customer_PK] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Customer_Id] [smallint] NULL,
    [Customer_Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Deleted_time] [datetime2](7) NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: *Assuming* you don't reuse your Primary Keys, then you could tell a row has been deleted by the PK's existence in the history table, and lack of existence in the non-history table.

Comment: If Customers table get full loaded then get multiple 'Tesla' rows with same Customer_PK in CustomerHistory table. Every insert, update or delete of Tesla row will be in History table.

Comment: So what is your unique identifier in your table then?

Comment: Customer_Id and Customer_Name combination should be unique.

Comment: "Should be unique"? To create a system versioned table, the table **must** have a primary key. [Creating a system-versioned temporal table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) Are you saying that the combination of `Customer_Id` and `Customer_Name` is your Primary Key? If so, I would suggest rethinking that; names are a poor choice of a primary key candidate.

Comment: Sorry. I modified Customer table. Customer_PK is primary key in Customers table. But there are no primary keys in History table. It is possible that same Customer_PK exist twice if Customer table get full loaded.

Comment: *"It is possible that same Customer_PK exist twice if Customer table get full loaded."* I would address that problem then. an `int` can have over 4 billion values; I doubt you would really end up with over 4 billion customers (the global population is ~8 Billion, so over half the world would be your customer) unless you have some serious data quality issues.

Comment: This is how database works. If you truncate Customers table and then insert again data, then you get all those insert rows to History table. If I do every day full load then I have at least 365 times Customer_PK in History table.

Comment: *"This is how database works. If you truncate Customers table and then insert again data, then you get all those insert rows to History table."* No it isn't, you can't `TRUNCATE` a system versioned table: [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=66eaff57dd91adebd18f334aec50d1b8)